# Recursive array

Tags: arrays, python

The following is a function to write a recursive function that accepts an array and a callback. Function returns true if a single value in array returns true when passed to the callback otherwise it returns false.

I have trouble understanding the "if not" line written here(line 4), how does the cb interact with arr? Please help.

```
def isOdd(num):
    if num%2==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
        
def someRecursive(arr, cb):
    if len arr == 0:
        return False
    if not(cb(arr[0])):     #Maybe till it is an empty array. DOUBT HERE
        return someRecursive(arr[1:],cb)
    return True
```

Comment: (While [programming questions are off-topic here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the relevant part from the [Python 3 reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not) reads *not_test ::=  comparison | "not" not_test […] The operator `not` yields `True` if its argument is false, `False` otherwise*. The parentheses around `cb(arr[0])` are dispensable. The statement in `isOdd(num)` might better read `return num%2;`, `return num%2 != 0;` or even `return not (num%2 == 0);`.)

Comment: `cb` is a function, so `cb(arr[0])` is simply calling `cb` with `arr[0]` as an argument. What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

The if not branches says that the program continues to recurse if the first element of the array does not satisfy `cb` (`cb(arr[0])` returns false).

The function checks the condition `cb` on one (the first) element at every call, and give the rest to the next recursion. Since the first element is removed at every iteration, `arr[0]` is different in each function call.

Once `not(cb(arr[0]))` gives false, the function returns True, and the return value propagates back to previous iterations.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response, I think I understand this code better now. Have a good day my friend!

Answer (score 1):

The function starts by checking for an empty array and returns *false* in that case.

Otherwise, it tests the first element of the array and returns *true* if the condition *cb* is met. Otherwise, it recurses with the array less the first element.

Said differently, the function recursively scans the array until some element fulfills the condition, and reports if there is one.

Comment: Off topic here but the python expression `any(cb(x) for x in arr)` produces the same boolean more efficiently.

Comment: @Gribouillis: doubly off-topic because the question was about recursion and the site is not about programming languages.